# how can we build android ndk from android code base

Tags: android, android-ndk

I wanna build an executable binary for android , compling in embedded linux devices, such as raspberrypi or nvidia jetson.
Is there any way to making android cross compiling toolchain from those devices, or i can use linux armeabi toolchain directly?

Appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Linux armeabi toolchain for Android, and Android NDK is only distributed for Windows, Linux and Mac OS for 64-bit x86. You can build Android NDK from sources for your platform, if that's your goal.

Comment: Yes, i wan to to build android ndk from sources for my platform.
but i don't know the build command for ndk, could you give some more information about building ndk from sources?
i haven't got the guideline from android dev website.
Thanks again!

Comment: found the description in below link, thank you very much.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/Building.md